# How can I allow my SIM900 IP address on my Hostgator database

Tags: database, arduino, ip, sim900

I'm trying to send data from a SIM900 to my database located at Hostgator.com; I have the correct PHP file and my Arduino file seems alright too. But It seems that the information doesn't go to my database. I tried allowing the IP address that I get from "AT+SAPBR=2,1", but it doesn't seem to work. I know that the PHP file is correct because I tested manually adding information to the database and it worked.

This is the Arduino code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Wire.h>

SoftwareSerial SIM900(7, 8);

float s1 = 55.44;
float s2 = 66.3;
float s3 = 77.2;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(19200);
  SIM900.begin(19200);

  delay(3000);

  // See if the SIM900 is ready
  SIM900.println("AT");
  ReceberEFim();                                 
  delay(4000);

  // SIM card inserted and unlocked?
  SIM900.println("AT+CPIN?");
  ReceberEFim();
  delay(500);              

  // Is the SIM card registered?
  SIM900.println("AT+CREG?");
  ReceberEFim();                            
  delay(500);

  // Is GPRS attached?
  SIM900.println("AT+CGATT?");
  ReceberEFim();                           
  delay(500);

  // Check signal strength - should be 9 or higher
  SIM900.println("AT+CSQ");
  ReceberEFim();                              
  delay(500);

  // Set connection type to GPRS
  SIM900.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"Contype\",\"GPRS\"");
  ReceberEFim();      
  delay(1000);

  // Set the APN - this will depend on your network/service provider
  SIM900.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"claro.com.br\"");
  ReceberEFim();      
  delay(1000);

  // Enable GPRS - this will take a moment or two
  SIM900.println("AT+SAPBR=1,1");
  ReceberEFim();                      
  delay(3000);

  SIM900.println("AT+SAPBR=2,1");
  ReceberEFim();                        
  delay(500);

  SIM900.println("AT+CIFSR");
  ReceberEFim();                        
  delay(500);

  SIM900.println("AT+HTTPINIT");
  ReceberEFim();                        
  delay(2000);

  SIM900.print("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://myweb.com/conexao.php?");
  SIM900.print("s1=");
  SIM900.print(s1);
  delay(50);
  SIM900.print("&s2=");
  SIM900.print(s2);
  delay(50);
  SIM900.print("&s3=");
  SIM900.print(s3);
  delay(50);
  SIM900.println("\"\r\n");   //Fechar URL
  ReceberEFim(); 
  delay(5000);

  SIM900.println("\nAT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\",1");
  ReceberEFim();             
  delay(500);

  SIM900.println("AT+HTTPACTION=0");
  ReceberEFim();                   
  delay(500);

  SIM900.println("AT+HTTPTERM");
  ReceberEFim();

  SIM900.println("AT+SAPBR=0,1");
  ReceberEFim();
}

void loop(){

}

void ReceberEFim() {
  while (SIM900.available()) {
    Serial.write(SIM900.read());
  }       
}
```

Comment: We'd love to help you with this issue. Can you please contact us at reputation@endurance.com and provide the primary email on your HostGator account and the best phone number to reach you? We're looking forward to hearing from you and resolving this issue. Thanks! Erinn
Customer Advocate at HostGator

Comment: Unfortunately Erinn doesn't quite yet get how to use Stack Overflow and doesn't have the reputation to reply (I had to convert an answer to a comment, something we don't usually do).

Comment: @Erinn If you really need my phone number, send me an email so I can send you the phone number from there.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the issue, actually, It was pretty simple, The problem was that my website had https and I was working with http, to fix it just simply change from http to https like this:

```
SIM900.print("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"https://myweb.com/conexao.php?");
```